# React Helmet not working on Build Command

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I have the following in my layout file to render out metadata. When I run the build command I noticed that it isn't creating this info in the index.html. So the information for title is the default title="React App" .

What am I missing here to render this on build?

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

import Site from './layout/Site'
import Header from './layout/Header'
import Content from './layout/Content'
import Footer from './layout/Footer'
import Router from './layout/Router'

const Layout = ({ children }) => (

  <Site>
    <Helmet
      title="Site name"
      meta={[
        { name: 'description', content: 'Site description goes here.' },
        { name: 'keywords', content: 'content, goes, here' },
        { name: 'msapplication-TileColor', content: '#ff4e35' },
        { name: 'theme-color', content: '#ffffff' }
      ]}
      script={[
        { 'src': ''},
      ]}
      link={[
        {'rel':'apple-touch-icon', 'size': '180x180', 'href': 'appleIcon'},
        {'rel':'icon', 'type': 'image/png', 'size': '32x32', 'href': 'icon32'},
        {'rel':'icon', 'type': 'image/png', 'size': '16x16', 'href': 'icon16'},
        {'rel':'manifest', 'href': 'webmanifest'},
        {'rel':'mask-icon', 'href': 'safari'}
      ]}
    />


        <header className="stuckinmud">
          <Header />
        </header>


        <Content>
          <Router />
        </Content>
        <Footer />


  </Site>
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func,
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: "When I run the build command I noticed that it isn't creating this info in the index.html." Why do you expect it to inline those values into index.html? This is runtime feature. If you need to change title statically you do it like this [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#changing-the-page-title)